# How to make a ListView or RecyclerView continue to load more data automatically until screen is filled

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I'm displaying a set of items in a `RecyclerView`. The data are downloaded from the server, and one group of items are downloaded for each time. However, sometimes only one group of data cannot fill the screen, so I want to make the `RecyclerView` capable of detecting this problem, and start loading next group of data until the screen is filled.

For example, if data of page 1 is not enough, load data of page 2. If still not, load data of page 3, and so on.

The detection part is not difficult since I can get the parameters below:

```
    int visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
    int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    int firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

But the problem comes with `notifyDataSetChanged()`. For example, below is my code of setting data:

```
public void setData(List data){
    updataData(data);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if(ifScreenNotFilled()){
       loadNextGroupData(); // it calls 'setData()' recursively
    }
}
```

When the `loadNextGroupData()` is called, the `setData` is called recursively. And it turns out that the size of data list keeps on expanding while the `visibleItemCount` is always zero, and nothing appears on the screen.

If I delete the recursion part of code, the 1st group of data is loaded in to screen. I become very curious of the mechanism of `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

So is there a solution to get the `RecyclerView` updated automatically when it does not fill the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason why `notifyDataSetChanged()` does not work. It's because the recursive invoking of the `setData()` method making it never returns. Thus the `notifyDataSetChanged()` could not be executed by the UI thread.

The solution is use a `Handler` to post the recursive part into the message queue of UI thread.

```
mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
public void setData(List data){
    updataData(data);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if(ifScreenNotFilled()){
       mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
             @override 
             public void run(){
                 loadNextGroupData();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

For those who may see this question later, the concrete implementaion of code above could be found in my repo: https://github.com/SphiaTower/AutoPagerRecyclerManager .

Please check the `setData()` method in https://github.com/SphiaTower/AutoPagerRecyclerManager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/tower/sphia/auto_pager_recycler/lib/AutoPagerRecyclerViewManager.java

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getHeight() on your mRecyclerView and to get it's height and compare it with display height.

```
    int height = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()
```

Comment: The main problem is how to load data recursively. Every time a group of data is loaded, it must be checked whether the screen is filled. If not, a new group of data should be loaded and the check will be executed again.

Comment: yes, so you could get display height in onCreate (to make sure that is is changed on device rotation) and then compare it with your recyclerView each time the data is loaded. If the screen is full after the latest upload then do nothing if not - load more.

Comment: Thank you but in fact the loading data and checking code are executed recursively. I know it is expected that the view on screen would be updated everytime data get updated, but it does not. The `notifyDataSetChanged()` does not work because the method never returns. So every time I check the height of recyclerview, the result would always be 0.